# Cucumber: Undefined step although the step is defined. You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets: is displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, cucumber, capybara

I've just started a new project and set up environment for it. I wrote my first step and trying to run it. 
But it doesn't see my step_defs although I've launched it to my .feature file and wrote a code. I was googling but no solution helped me (. 
The structure of my project is : 
project-name - > cucumber -> features -> step_defs

I would appreciate your help.

I am using Cucumber - Capybara - Rails

Comment: Show the line that’s giving the error and your step definition that’s supposed to match it

Comment: **Step Def:** Given(/^I am on "([^"]*)" page$/) do |page|
  visit page
  binding.pry
end

Comment: **error line in terminal:** You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given("I am on {string} page") do |string|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Comment: it happens with all step definition files ( and launched to it features) I think problem is in my project ( configs probably)

Comment: By default Cucumber will load setps from `<project_root>/features/**/*.rb` .  Since you've put them under a "cucumber" directory that's probably what's causing no steps to be loaded.  Rearrange your directories or add `cucumber/features/**/*.rb` to the load path.

Comment: Thank you , Thomas ! I was thinking about that as a reason...I've already rearranged my project structure so that i do not have cucumber folder. Now  my project structure is : project-name -> features -> step_definitions. I had some issues with gems - and It seems I fixed it. Now it works fine and sees my code. Thank you a lot